# Call a functions for unassociated twig template files

Tags: php, twig

So I have 2 files "header.html" & "footer.html", they are included in all my template files
The problem is that I have a dropdown menu in my header were I list all categories and I didn't find any method to render functions/variables because the header file is not associated with any PHP file

(I'm not using any PHP framework)

Comment: simply change file extension from .html to .php and then try

Comment: That's an option I avoided, I'll only do that if I didn't find any solution

Comment: If you want to use PHP related functionality then file extension should be .php

Comment: If you have time just check it out how to integrate twig with php http://devzone.zend.com/1886/creating-web-page-templates-with-php-and-twig-part-1/

Comment: All pages are already integrated with twig, only footer & header are not

Answer (score 0):

"the header file is not associated with any PHP file"

I assume that the template they are included into is, or is associated with, a php file though. Since the include is the same as copy/paste, the template file can insert the catageories into a php placeholder in the header file. So just set a placeholder into the header and populate it in the page file that includes the header.